# SQL. Ни как не могу понять JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть база данных, в ней три таблицы:

- пользователи `users (id:integer, name:string, created_at:datetime)`
- счетчики `meters (id:integer, user_id:integer, serial:string, created_at:datetime)`
- показания счетчиков `meter_values (id:interger, meter_id:integer, value:float, created_at:datetime)`

Написать запросы:

- Вывести 10 последних пользователей
- Вывести серийные номера счетчиков
  и имя пользователя
- Вывести пользователей без счетчиков
- Вывести серийный номер счетчика и последнее показание

Comment: Допишите как пробовали писать выборки - тогда получится вас поправить

Comment: Только две. SELECT  FROM ‘user’ ORDER BY name DESC LIMIT 10.                                                                                                       
SELECT meters.serial, user.name FROM meters, JOIN user
ON meters.user_id = user.name

Comment: В итоге должно быт ь4 запроса?

Comment: Да. Запутался со связями в таблицах

Comment: В таблицах при джойне должны быть связи, а я их никак не могу увидеть

Comment: Так там связей всего две.  **users.id = meters.user_id** и **meters.id = meter_values.meter_id**